# Want to go from DALLAS to LONDON via BERLIN

Tags: wordplay

Feel like going to LONDON from DALLAS but take a detour in BERLIN by the word change game.

All are six letter towns. You can change up to TWO letters at a time and make a new word. The new 6 letter word MUST BE a town, village, city, commune in Europe.

Cannot rearrange letters before or after the change.

Can you go from DALLAS to BERLIN to LONDON in 7 steps or less?

Comment: No towns/cities in USA count?

Comment: Well. Most US towns have derived their names from Europe anyway. If you can do it in less than 7 steps with US towns I would be very interested in knowing

Comment: Should the steps be geographically logical (going from West to East to North) or any valid town name is ok?

Comment: Any valid names OK

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here it is in 6 easy steps staying entirely in Europe

> DALLAS 
>  BALLAN (France)
>  BARLIN (Germany)
>  BERLIN 
>  BORLON (Belgium) 
>  BORDON (England) 
>  LONDON

Thanks to  [@Forklift](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53606/37805) for being the first to find the BERLIN->LONDON leg. I tried to find an original path, but until Bondon, Vietnam somehow moves to Europe I think that's the only one.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! This looks like it will be hard to beat

Comment: [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PTOBzZWtAwn4P2jHjStk0ERYw3i3z22F247zMcWs5SA/edit?usp=sharing) is a quick proof to why this is the minimum possible

Comment: I found a Ballon  but not a Ballan. There is a Ballen too, This is based on UN LOCODES. Can you name the source?

Comment: I first found it here [link](http://www.tiptopglobe.com/city?i=732784&n=Ballan) although it looks like it's refered to as Ballan-Mire officially [link](https://www.insee.fr/fr/metadonnees/cog/commune/COM37018-ballan-mire)

Comment: There may be a suitable Ballan in Albania or Italy: [see here](http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=ballan&country=&featureClass=P&continentCode=EU).

Answer (score 5):

I've done it in 6 steps in Europe with definitely real places (as in I can find them on Wikipedia)!

> [DALLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas) (US)
>  1 [DALL**ON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallon) (Fr)
>  2 [**BE**LLON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellon,_Charente) (Fr)
>  3 [BE**R**L**I**N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin) (De)
>  4 [BER**NO**N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernon) (Fr)
>  5 [B**O**R**D**ON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bordon) (UK)
>  6 [**L**O**N**DON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London) (UK)

Comment: There is Ballon in Ireland also I think

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar There is, but that would take an extra step in this sequence.

Answer (score 4):

I've got to LONDON in 7 steps:

> DALLAS
>  DULLES (Virginia)
>  DULLIN (France)
>  DEBLIN (Poland)
>  BERLIN
>  BORLON (Belgium)
>  BORDON (UK)
>  LONDON

Comment: Cool Forklift.  Now try Europe only??

Comment: @Forklift as a first-timer solves it :P